# Qt forbid declaration of QListView with no type

Tags: qt, qlistview, qlistwidget

I have a very strange error in my Qt project. Here is the code, the main_window.h:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtSql>

class main_window : public QTabWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    /// @name List Widgets
private:
    QListWidget*    m_documents_list;
....
```

and here is main_window.cpp:

```
...
void main_window::create_documents_widget()
{
    m_documents = new QWidget(this);
    m_documents_list = new QListWidget(m_documents);
}
...
```

The problem that I can't understand is in QListView, I'm not using it in my project. There is only QListWidget, but when I'm trying to build the project the following errors occur:

***qlistview.h:194: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QListView' with no type***

***qlistview.h:194: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token***

Also the following strange errors:

***qlistwidget.h:308: error: no 'void QListWidget::removeItemWidget(QListWidgetItem***)' member function declared in class 'QListWidget'*

***qlistwidget.h:311: error: no 'void QListWidget::addItem(QListWidgetItem***)' member function declared in class 'QListWidget'*

***qlistwidget.h:314: error: no 'QListWidgetItem*** QListWidget::itemAt(int, int) const' member function declared in class 'QListWidget'*

etc.

Thanks in advance.

**UPD**: I'm using QtCreator 2.2.1 on Windows 7.

**UPD2**: Qt version is 4.7.1.

**UPD3**: The complete output

```
In file included from c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/QtGui:68,
                 from ..\my_project\/main_window.h:4,
                 from ..\my_project\main.cpp:2:
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistview.h:194: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QListView' with no type
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistview.h:194: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistview.h:194: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QListView' with no type
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistview.h:194: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QListView' with no type
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistview.h:194: error: expected ';' before '&' token
In file included from c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/QtGui:69,
                 from ..\my_project\/main_window.h:4,
                 from ..\my_project\main.cpp:2:
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistwidget.h:202: error: redefinition of 'class QListWidget'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistview.h:58: error: previous definition of 'class QListWidget'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistwidget.h:308: error: no 'void QListWidget::removeItemWidget(QListWidgetItem*)' member function declared in class 'QListWidget'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistwidget.h:311: error: no 'void QListWidget::addItem(QListWidgetItem*)' member function declared in class 'QListWidget'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistwidget.h:314: error: no 'QListWidgetItem* QListWidget::itemAt(int, int) const' member function declared in class 'QListWidget'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistwidget.h: In member function 'void QListWidgetItem::setSelected(bool)':
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistwidget.h:318: error: 'class QListWidget' has no member named 'setItemSelected'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistwidget.h: In member function 'bool QListWidgetItem::isSelected() const':
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistwidget.h:321: error: 'class QListWidget' has no member named 'isItemSelected'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistwidget.h: In member function 'void QListWidgetItem::setHidden(bool)':
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistwidget.h:324: error: 'class QListWidget' has no member named 'setItemHidden'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistwidget.h: In member function 'bool QListWidgetItem::isHidden() const':
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include\QtGui/qlistwidget.h:327: error: 'class QListWidget' has no member named 'isItemHidden'
```

Comment: Could you show the complete compilation output (or at least the lines before these error) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly - you should also mention qt version, as in this case that's most important.

This seems like some weird quirk of compiler or qt - my recomendation would be first to create simplest program where problem occurs. If it shows also in program like

```
#include <QtGui/QListWidget>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QListWidget* w = 0;
}
```

then it is some problem with qt headers of compiler - then answer cannot be provided from data provided. If it works, then try to slowly add other elements of your code to this simple file - most likely at some point you will get the same error again - then you will know that last added piece of code is guilty. Some additional thinking might be required to figure out how to remove problem once located.

Comment: Thanks, tried and appeared the same problem when I just added "#include <QtGui/QListWidget>". Does it mean I have problems in Qt headers? Or Qt itself has problems? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Firstly make sure that in your simple directory there is no other file than your source before compilation - sometimes I observed some weird, unexplained inteeractions - if it doesn't help, then apparently your build system is somehow broken (either Qt or compiler itself) - if it's not a big problem to you I would recommend firstly uninstalling Qt and compiler (on windows shouldn't be much work) and installing it again - or at least trying to make independent installation in another directory and using it.

Comment: Thanks @j_kubik, will inform on finish.

Comment: Have chosen this as best because of the comment up to mine.

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that QListWidget inherits from QListView, so you are indirectly using it.

The error your getting looks like you're simply missing a `#include <QListWidget>` line in your header file.

Also, it could be that that you're missing #include guards in your header file

```
#ifndef MYCLASS
#define MYCLASS

class MyClass { ... };

#endif
```

If your header file is #included by more than one project then that would explain the errors you're seeing.

Comment: Shouldn't #include <QtGui> take care of that?

Comment: Nope.  In fact I'm not sure what including QtGui actually gives you.  As a general rule each widget in Qt needs to be #included separately.

Comment: #include <QtGui> is causing all headers from QtGui module to be included - anyway error messages directly state that qlistwidget.h is included during compilation.

Comment: I added the possibility of missing #include guards in the header file.